# Fill ArrayList with hashmaps

Tags: java

I want to fill an *ArrayList* (**Appointment_List**) with *HashMap*'s (**Appointment**), but each time I need to change the value of specified elements(**Appt_Start_Time** and **endtime**).

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < Appt_Length; i++) {
    Start_Time = End_Time;
    Start_Minute = Curr_Start_Minute;
    Start_Minute += My_Calendar.Get_Time_Interval();
    if (Start_Minute >= 60) {
        Tmp_Start_Hour += 1;
        Curr_Start_Minute = 0;
    } else {
        Curr_Start_Minute = Start_Minute;
    }
    End_Time = Time.Get_Index_Time(Tmp_Start_Hour, Curr_Start_Minute);
    Appointment.remove("Appt_Start_Time");
    Appointment.put("Appt_Start_Time", Start_Time);
    Appointment.remove("endtime");
    Appointment.put("endtime", End_Time);
    Appointment_List.add(Appointment);
}
```

But after I execute this code I got the appointments in the **Appointment_List** but all of them have `Appointment.get("Appt_Start_Time")` and `Appointment.get("endtime")` equals to last values the loop come with.

Why is **Appt_Start_Time** and **endtime** reseted each time, when I add a new element?

Comment: Your PHP/C style naming conventions doesn't help much to interpret your code snippet seamlessly. When writing Java, try to adhere the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I think you might have an off-by-one error in your loop. Are you sure you don't want to start with i = 0?

Answer (score 1):

Appointment is THE SAME HashMap instance every iteration. You should do something like that:

`Appointment = new HashMap();`

`// ... do something with appointment ...`

`Appointment_List.add(Appointment)`

This way you'll put a fresh new map to the list each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your objects hold a reference to the Start_Time. Since you keep reusing the same variable, only thing that changes is the pointer to the object. That way, all your objects have a field that points to the same object.

Try using a new implementation of a Date for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: what do you mean by "new implementation of a Date "?

Comment: What I mean is that you create a new instance of the variable.

Comment: sorry can you help me by coding what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Use `clone()` when adding a new object to the map.

When adding an object to a map, the added object is only referenced by the map.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new instance of Start_Time and End_Time in the for loop.
If you don't, the same object gets added every single time, thus also pointing to the same data in your memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should look  more like this:

```
public class Appointment {
    public Appointment(Date startTime, Date endTime) {
    }
}

public void fillAppointments() {
    int totalAppointments = 10;
    List<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
    Date startTime = new Date();
    Date endTime = new Date();
    for (int i = 1; i < totalAppointments; i++) {
        startTime = new Date(endTime.getTime());
        // ... other magic code ...
        endTime = new Date();
        appointments.add(new Appointment(startTime, endTime));
    }
}
```